# Doing an executive MBA after a PhD

Tags: phd, masters, career-path

I have a PhD in Physics and about 10 years of experience post the PhD, 6 years in academia and the rest in Industry as a research Data Scientist. I would like to move more towards management and am considering an executive MBA. Another reason for considering the MBA is that my PhD was from US and then I returned back to India. Now I am looking to go back and considering this as an avenue to return to US. Does it sound like a reasonable idea?

Answer (score 1):

IF you're already a data scientist, then many US firms are crying out for your skills, and willing to pay really good salaries. I'd have a look at coming across to the US in employment as a data scientist with a good company that will probably be willing to invest in management training. The danger with the MBA route (assuming you mean full time at a good business school) is high cost outlay together with a period with no income - but then again only you know your financial position!